# Calling an UnmanagedFunctionPointer in C# for custom calling conventions

Tags: c#, pinvoke, function-pointers, unsafe

I have a function in a DLL:

```
char __usercall MyUserCallFunction<al>(int arg1<esi>)
```

Because I hate myself I'd like to call this from within C# using P/Invoke.

Normally this can be done by getting a function delegate, a la:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public delegate char DMyUserCallFunction(IntPtr a1);
```

And then invoking it by doing:

```
var MyFunctionPointer = (DMyUserCallFunction)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(AddressOfFunction, typeof(DMyUserCallFunction));

MyFunctionPointer(IntPtr.Zero);
```

For custom user calling conventions, however, this will cause the program to crash. Is there some sort of way I can do this using unsafe code or some sort of wrapper function that puts the delegates in place, but doesn't force me to write a C++ DLL?

Thanks!

Edit:

As suggested by dtb, I created a very small C++ DLL which I use via P/Invoke to call the function. For anyone curious the function in C++ ends up looking like:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall callUsercallFunction(int functionPointer, int arg1 )
{
    int retVal;

    _asm 
    {
        mov esi, arg1
        call functionPointer
        mov retVal, eax
    }

    //Fake returning al, the lower byte of eax
    return retVal & 0x000000FF;
}
```

Comment: +1 for "Because I hate myself"

Comment: Why do you need the delegate at all? Can't you do `[DllImport(...)] public extern byte MyUserCallFunction(IntPtr a1)`?

Comment: The function isn't actually exported. I need to call the function by injecting into a process which loads the DLL. I'm using EasyHook for this - the goal is to hook any arbitrary function I can find using IDA inside the DLL.

Comment: You raise a good point though - is there a way I can define a call into the DLL if it's not an exported function but I know the address?

Comment: I don't want to force you to hate yourself less, but I think writing a C wrapper would be the path of least resistance. I'm not aware of any way to trick a P/Invoke call into calling a non-exported function. Maybe someone can help you with the calling convention problem, but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hope of implementing custom calling conventions in C#. You must do this in either a native DLL or a C++/CLI DLL.